# Using Readable stream in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

I am blocked when in this following exercice when it's about to set a intervall timer one-second intervals. Can you help to see more clearer ?

Thank you for your help.

Exercise 1: Creating a Simple Readable Stream

Create a Readable Stream that emits numbers from 1 to 10 using the Readable class. The numbers should be emitted one by one at one-second intervals.

```
let {Readable}=require(`stream`);


class MyReadable extends Readable{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    _read(){// logique du traitement des données

        for( let i=1;i<=10;i++){
            this.push(i.toString());

        }

        this.push(null)// fin du push des données
    }
}

let InstanceReadableStream= new MyReadable();

InstanceReadableStream.on("data", (chunk)=>{
    console.log(chunk.toString())
})


InstanceReadableStream.on("end",()=>console.log("Fin de la lecture des données"))
```

I have tried, but setting intervall timer become difficult for me.

Comment: Tell your teacher that it would be better to use standard spec'ed web streams instead for better cross env. functionality

Comment: @Endless - If you're programming in the nodejs environment, you can do a lot more with the built-in nodejs library when using nodejs streams, not web streams.